# GPS EXIF data from Capacitor Camera

Tags: capacitor

The Camera plugin doesnt capture GPS data when taking a photo but oddly it does extract the GPS data when adding from the gallery.  Is there a reason for this or is this just an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean on iOS, because on android the Exif is not returned (just fixed it last week but isn’t released yet).

Sadly the native iOS component that the camera plugin uses doesn’t capture the user location when you take a picture, so the gps information is not provided.
But when you pick the picture from the galley, it will contain the gps information if the picture in the gallery already had gps information.